# Simulate M Geometric Brownian motion paths in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and I'm currently trying to simulate M paths of GBM(Geometric Brownian motions) in VBA. I know this can be done with excel, but I would still like to know how we can get this done in VBA for my personal knowledge. Here is my code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim dt As Double, T As Integer, N As Integer, M As Integer, S As Double, mu As Double _
    , sig As Double, drift As Double, diff As Double, i As Integer, j As Integer
    
    mu = 0.15
    sig = 0.2
    T = 1
    N = 365
    M = 100
    S = 150.5
    dt = T / N
    
    
    Dim mat() As Variant
    ReDim mat(1 To M, 1 To (N + 1)) As Variant
    
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(mat)
        mat(i, 1) = S
    Next
    
    
    
    For i = 1 To M
        For j = 2 To (T + 1)
            drift = (mu + 0.5 * sig^(2)) * dt
            diff = Sqr(dt) * WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(Rnd, 0, 1)
            
            mat(i, j) = mat(i, j - 1) * Exp(drift + diff)
            
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

**First issue**

My equations seem to be correct. The main issue that I'm having is with variable types. For instance, I get an overflow error when assigning the value 0.15 to mu, 0.2 to sig (mu = 0.15, sig = 0.2, etc.). I don't really understand why I get that error since mu and sig are defined as doubles, just like the values that I want to assign to them (0.15 and 0.20).

**Second issue**

A non-efficient way to get around my first issue is to declare all variables as variants. Even when all my variables are declared as variants, my second loop does not run.

Here is my second loop:

```
For i = 1 To M
    For j = 2 To (T + 1)
        drift = (mu + 0.5 * sig^(2)) * dt
        diff = Sqr(dt) * WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(Rnd, 0, 1)

        mat(i, j) = mat(i, j - 1) * Exp(drift + diff)

    Next
Next
```

More specifically, I get the same overflow error when i try to assign a value to a specific element of my array (i.e. mat(i, j) = mat(i, j - 1) * Exp(drift + diff)).

Does anyone know how I can solve those issues?

- Note that I'm using the latest VBA version for Macbook.

Answer (score 0):

With VBA 7.1 (Windows), I made it work with adding some space in your exponent formula ( sig ^ (2) ):

```
For i = 1 To M
    For j = 2 To (T + 1)
        drift = (mu + 0.5 * sig ^ (2)) * dt
        diff = Sqr(dt) * WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(Rnd, 0, 1)
        
        mat(i, j) = mat(i, j - 1) * Exp(drift + diff)
        Debug.Print mat(i, j)
    Next
Next
```

I don't see any problem with double type, you're right.

No overflow error...

Comment: That's weird. It must probably come form the fact that I'm using VBA on a mac; this is such a basic task so I don't understand why its bugging... Thanks for checking out my code though!